# "pip install psycopg2" not working on Linux (pg_config executable not found)

Tags: python, path, pip, psycopg2, pg-config

Trying to install psycopg2 package on Linux using:
pip install psycopg2

Getting the following error:

Error: pg_config executable not found.

```
pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:
         python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build
```

After running "python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build",

I get the following error:

"python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Can someone explain how I add the directory containing pg_config to the $PATH?

Also, I am doing all of these commands in a virtualenv.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+pg_config+is+required+to+build+psycopg2+from+source

Comment: Try to `pip install psycopg2-binary` instead.

Comment: tried that as well then re ran "pip install psycopg2" and getting same error